# Inserting HTML to fancybox close button

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I would like to use html instead of an image for the fancybox close button.

Here's what I think should work:

```
$('.fancybox-media').fancybox({
    afterLoad : function() {
        $('div.fancybox-close').html('X');
    }
});
```

Just focusing on the close button here. Any ideas why this isn't working?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For fancybox v2.x you can use the option `tpl` to set whatever html you want like

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
 tpl: {
  closeBtn: '<div title="Close" id="myCloseID ">[CLOSE]</div>'
 }
});
```

Notice that in this example I set my own selector `id="myCloseID "` to the `close` container (`closeBtn`) so I can add my own css style to the new html like :

```
#myCloseID {
 position: absolute; /* this is important */
 z-index: 8040; /* this is important */
 top: -18px; /* or whatever needed */
 right: -10px;
 width: 50px; /* or whatever needed */
 height: 36px;
 cursor: pointer;
 color : #ff0034; /* or whatever needed */
 /* etc. */
}
```

Eventually, you may prefer to use the default `tpl` for the `closeBtn` with your own html

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
 tpl: {
  closeBtn: '<div title="Close" class="fancybox-item fancybox-close">[my closing html]</div>'
 }
});
```

...and just remove the background image through css like

```
.fancybox-close {
 background-image: none; /* prevents the use of the fancybox sprite */
 color : #ff0034; /* or whatever needed, etc. */
 /* etc. */
}
```

Comment: So, I'm WAY late on this. I'm really sorry I didn't get to you before. The client ended up halting the project before I implemented your fix. However, I went back and tested this out and it worked beautifully!

Thank you!!

Comment: Oh and also, all I needed was the tpl part.

Comment: Oh and here's a working example if anyone is interested: http://codepen.io/DavidVII/full/qJxnf

Answer (score 1):

It should work, but you would also need to set the `background` to `none`.

Try this:

```
$('div.fancybox-close').html('X').css({background:'none',color:'white'});
```

Comment: Thanks, for your reply Moin. Unfortunately, that didn't work.

Comment: Are you sure? The X may be in a black color font and can't be seen?

Comment: Yep, totally sure. I changed the color in css to be white against a black background. Nothing there.

Comment: Does an `alert` in the afterLoad work? You could try the `afterShow` callback instead of `afterLoad`

Comment: Could you put up a demo of your code on jsbin.com or jsfiddle.net ?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
$('.fancybox-close').html('X').css({background:'none',color:'white'});
```

Comment: This is the essentially the same thing that Moin said. It also doesn't work, sorry.